# Problem understanding this use of template for function

Tags: c++, templates, function

I have used templates for types of parameters, but I came across this thing and I'm not really sure I understand what's going on or have ever read about it.

```
template<char *name, int iteration, bool high>
void test( short step )
{
   if(high)
     iteration++;
   change(name,iteration);
}

template void test<"John", 5, true>( short );
```

EDIT : if(bool) was clearly a mistake replaced it by the right thing.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but I'll risk a guess: Google for "non-type template parameters".

Comment: If you are going to post code. Use **Copy and Paste** there is nothing worse than miss copied code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is going on.  The template is just being declared and then explicitly instantiated.  It's not being called.

In fact, I doubt it compiles.  I don't think `if (bool)` is a valid expression.

Another reason it doesn't compile is that a string literal cannot be a template parameter.  I really wish it could be because it would be quite useful in a lot of metaprogramming constructs I've used.  In order to pass a char* to a template you have to do this:

```
extern char * param = "whatever";
expects_char_param<param>();
```

And even if this function DID work, and compiled, and `bool` was replaced with `high` in the body, it would be an incredibly stupid way of doing it.  To figure out WHAT it does though, just pretend the parameters are variables, like they should be, and walk through the code.  If you still don't understand...  dunno what to tell you.

Comment: I think he meant `if (high)`.

Comment: Not at the moment.  I think the author of the code might be though :p

Comment: Ok then from what I understand it was used to kind of dodge making macros for making functions?

Comment: It was probably some stupid attempt to create "optimal" code.  The author of that code obviously doesn't understand C++ and probably thinks that by making everything a compile time constant he/she is making sure all the code is uber-fast.  I doubt there'd be any gains even if it worked.  But yeah, the end result would be a whole crap load of functions that all do the same thing with different values; functions that may or may not end up inlined.

Comment: For some reason that `if(bool)` had me cracking up...  Kind of the equivalent of seeing someone try to eat a recipe book.

Comment: I wanted to upvote it, until i read the `extern char *param` code :) That one only works as a argument if you have a `char *&` parameter. If you have a `char*` parameter, you want to say `extern char program[] = "whatever"`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in hell that this code will compile. First, you can't pass string literals via template. Second, `if (bool)`?

The reason you don't understand it is because it's uncompilable nonsense.

Comment: Interestingly, someone on the boost list figured out a way to make string literal metavariables.  I and a couple others worked with him on it and it's now part of the MPL as boost::mpl::string.  It's pretty sub-optimal but does the trick.  Instantiated like so: `mpl::string<'hell', 'lo w', 'orld'>`

Answer (score 1):

That template is completely broken.  For one thing, as Noah Roberts has already mentioned, `if(bool)` won't even compile.  For another, `iteration` is a template parameter, meaning it must be a compile-time constant, so `iteration++;` won't compile either.

Comment: hehehe oh yeah :p  missed that one.